# In Azure DevOps, can I create a query that calculates project health based on PBI data?

Tags: azure-devops, reporting

Using the Scrum process template, I'd like to be able to create a query that I can use to display a pie chart on my overview page. This pie chart would essentially display a breakdown of PBIs in red/green/yellow status.

Criteria for each might be:

- Red: Blocked
- Yellow: Not blocked AND (X days elapsed since work began)
- Green: Not blocked, on time

Ideally, this information would roll up to the feature and epic levels (any feature that has a red or yellow PBI is red, respectively, and any epic that has a red or yellow feature is a red or yellow feature, respectively). But that's entirely optional at this point.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to create a query to accomplish the base query. It might not be possible, and I can live with that.

Is the only solution to this problem to create an extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just answered your own question ;-)

Yes, the only way to achieve this sort of accumulation is to write your own extension.

Comment: It's not the answer I was hoping for, but I can deal with it. Thank you for your response.